# Como manter a fonte no Qt5 quando aumenta o DPI

Tags: c++, qt, ui, dpi

Estou com problemas quando passo minha UI para um usuário que tem uma configuração visual do windows diferente da minha. Se o display do usuario estiver em 125 ou 150% meu UI fica com fontes enormes nos labels enquanto os outros widgets ficam padrao. Queria manter a fonte dos labels fixa.

Ja tentei:

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

ja setei DPI fico em 96 e nada.

ja tentei usar um  .config

```
[Platforms]
WindowsArguments = dpiawareness=0 , 1 ou 2
```

e ja tentei setar uma variável nas configurações do projeto mas nada disso funcionou, existe algum jeito de fazer essas configurações funcionarem?

a configuração de fonte que uso é a padrão do Qt5 Designer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o meu main.cpp do código fica da seguinte forma:

```
#include "meu_UI.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_Use96Dpi);
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    meu_UI w;

    w.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Primeira coisa: você está setando as fontes em pixels ou em pontos? A Qt permite as 2 formas, setPixelSize e setPointSize, convém você usar um padrão fixo (pontos usualmente são melhores para acomodar estas situações, mas cada caso é um caso). O melhor mesmo seria você [edit] seu post com um [Mcve] demonstrando o problema.

Comment: Eu uso tamanho mas parece não ser afetado pelas configurações.